# Why cant I add 2 doubles together

Tags: java, render, frame-rate

So I am making a simple game with spites. But im having some issues with the tick/render loop.

I need it to run at 30 ticks a second. But the fps needs to be as fast as it can.

The issue I am having is the while loop doesn't run

```
lastTime += msPerTick;
```

So my output looks like this. No adding. No loop. No render.

```
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
x:0.375 y:0.03333333333333333
```

Here is a snippet of the code. Let me know if you need more.

```
public  static final int  TICKS_PER_SECOND = 30;
private static final int  MAX_TICKS_PER_FRAME = 10;
private boolean       running;
private Thread        thread;
private int           tickCount;
private int           frames;
private boolean       paused;

public void run() {
    init();
    float lastTime = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000) / 1000.0f;
    running = true;

    double msPerTick = 1.0 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;

    while (running) {
        synchronized (this) {
            float now = (System.nanoTime() / 1000000) / 1000.0f;
            int frameTicks = 0;
            while (now - lastTime > msPerTick) {
                System.out.println("x:" + (now - lastTime) + " y:" + msPerTick);

                if (!paused && frameTicks++ < MAX_TICKS_PER_FRAME) 
                    tick();


                lastTime += msPerTick; //<-- Issue here
            }

            if (!paused) {
                render((now - lastTime) / msPerTick);
            }
        }

        //Thread.yield(); No need for yield lets use sleep.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(paused ? 500 : 1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not adding 2 doubles. If you change the type of lastTime to double the code will work fine.

float f = (float) 0.2;
double d = 2;

f += d  => 2.0
d += f  => 2.2

Comment: I would give you a cookie if I could. Well that explains everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an algorithm problem here which happens if your render action takes less than 1/30 second.

When you start the outer loop executes multiple times for 1/30 seconds without entering the inner loop.  At the 1/30 second mark it enters the inner loop exactly once and then spends another 1/30 seconds looping in the outer loop.

If the render takes more than 1/30 seconds then you should not have the problem.

You cannot rely on the Thread.yield() to do much of anything.

Comment: But im getting stuck in the inner loop. Not the outer loop. I also switch yield to sleep.

Comment: Try putting a print statement in the outer loop to see how often it is called.